# Observed weird behavior with @javax.ws.rs.Encoded

Tags: java, web-services, rest, cxf, jax-rs

I have rest method with @javax.ws.rs.Path("/{input:.+}") in my service to accept any value for "input" pathparam. Sample code here.

```
@GET
@Path("/{input:.+}")
@Produces({ XML })
public Response getByInput(@PathParam("input") @Encoded String input,
                                 @Context javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo uriInfo)
```

@Encoded annotation will prevent the decoding pathparam,queryparam and formparams.
But in my case if the input contains

1. `%2B` is getting decoded into `+`
2. `%2F` is getting encoded into `%252F`.

Using SoapUI to test the rest service, here is the sample request:

```
Req 1: GET /rest/Ca%2B2siaeevAg9BkOLKkMmgwlZ20%3D
   the value of input = Ca+2siaeevAg9BkOLKkMmgwlZ20=
   But i am expecting Ca%2B2siaeevAg9BkOLKkMmgwlZ20%3D
Req 2: GET /rest/Ca%2F2siaeevAg9BkOLKkMmgwlZ20%3D
   the value of input = Ca%252F2siaeevAg9BkOLKkMmgwlZ20=
   But i am expecting Ca%2F2siaeevAg9BkOLKkMmgwlZ20%3D
```

Why this is behaving differently for %2B and %2F?

Can you please help me,i have to fix this in my project.

Comment: What JAX-RS implementation are you using?

Comment: org.apache.cxf:cxf-bundle:2.2.12 using gradle.

Comment: @JohnAment, using JSR311-api-1.1.1 version as Jax-RS implementation. Thanks.